# Conditional excluding of blocks

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a long list of cronjobs that are common across all environments and short list which is specific to some markets.

As per the documentation of [if/else](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#ifelse), I can conditionally **include** blocks of text in the template. As the list to include is too large as most markets need it, I would prefer to exclude specific blocks.

As I am looping over a list of markets on a CronJob template, I am looking for an if/else condition to skip a particular iteration when the condition matches.

Something like:

```
{{- range $job := $.Values.cronjobs }}
{{- range $markets := $.Values.markets }}
{{- if and (eq $job "special") (eq $markets "ordinary") }}
<<---skip templating the below block of code--->>
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  namespace: {{ $.Release.Namespace }}
[...]
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Why you need to skip the entire metadata? `apiVersion`, `kind`. `metadata` etc. would be same for all.

Comment: @Bimal Because the whole template is a single resource of CronJob kind and I am creating multiple of these looping over a list of mappings holding only the name, schedule and args.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can negate the condition so that the block is only generated when it's false:

```
{{- if not ( and (eq $job "special") (eq $markets "ordinary") ) }}
```

Comment: Took me a while but figured out how to use it. No mention of the not operator in the v3 doc and a vague mention in v2 didn't help much either. :) Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Helm templating is basically an extension of Go templating + Sprig library - so you can always consult the template package docs: https://pkg.go.dev/text/template?tab=doc and the Sprig docs: https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/

Comment: I have never coded in Golang yet. Seems like I need to start spending some time on this as I have decided to use Helm for my deployments.